# BreakPoints in Foundation FrameWork

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

// Small screens

```
@media only screen { } /* Define mobile styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */
```

// Medium screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { } /* min-width 641px, medium screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { } /* min-width 641px and max-width 1024px, use when QAing tablet-only issues */
```

// Large screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) { } /* min-width 1025px, large screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) { } /* min-width 1025px and max-width 1440px, use when QAing large screen-only issues */
```

// XLarge screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) { } /* min-width 1441px, xlarge screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) and (max-width: 120em) { } /* min-width 1441px and max-width 1920px, use when QAing xlarge screen-only issues */
```

// XXLarge screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) { } /* min-width 1921px, xxlarge screens */
```

Above is Foundation Framework Standard Break Points.
For Mobile it is Seen the break Point is max-width of 640, What if Design Provided to me for mobile is greater than 640 & same is Case for Destkop & tablet. Does it make a sense in changing the Foundation breakpoints wrt to design provided? An answer with proper reasoning would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that make sense, you can adapt the framework to your project needs; most of time you can use the existing breakpoints (what Zurb have defined according to their most-of-time scenarios), but you can adapt if your project has specific needs, you can do it.

What I'd recommend to you, is not to use the basic foundation package (precompiled), but use any ["sass customizable" version](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/installation.html) instead (you can do that trough a lot of package managers), so you'll have full control of the framework, through customizing variables.

In Foundation's settings file, section **d.**, you can edit the media query ranges (a.k.a. the breakpoint ranges), next time you compile the framework, you'll have the breakpoints just as you need them.